# is there a cubic or quartic approximation for these data points?

Tags: approximation, cubics, quartics

Is there a cubic or quartic approximation for these data points; $$(0,1000000), (1000000, 100), (10000000, 10)$$ whilst also ensuring that no point from $$1000000 < x < 10000000$$ is greater than |100|?

I can currently fit the data points successfully with a cubic but  have no Idea how to enforce the upper bound restriction on the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit the three data points with a quadratic polynomial.
You don't need a cubic for that step. If you use a quadratic polynomial $f(x),$
then you will have $f(x) \leq \lvert 100 \rvert = 100$ for all
$x \in (10^6, 10^7)$
(that is, for all $x$ such that $1\,000\,000 < x < 10\,000\,000$).
That satisfies the requirement that you literally wrote,
that the value can't be greater than $\lvert 100 \rvert.$

But the value of $f(5\,500\,000)$ will be very negative.

I suppose the reason you are having difficulty is that you actually want to have $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq 100$ for $x \in (10^6, 10^7)$,
not $f(x) \leq \lvert 100 \rvert.$
So $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leq 100$ is the requirement I assume in this answer.

---

Let $f(x)$ be your desired polynomial.
You require that $-100 \leq f(x) \leq 100$ for $10^6 < x < 10^7.$

Consider $f(a),$ and $f(a + 5\times10^5)$ where $10^6 \leq a \leq 9.5\times10^6.$
By the Mean Value Theorem (MVT) there must be a number $a_1$ in the interval
$(a, a + 5\times10^5)$ such that
$$
f'(a_1) = \frac{f(a + 5\times10^5) - f(a)}{(a + 5\times10^5) - a}
 = \frac{f(a + 5\times10^5) - f(a)}{5\times10^5}.
$$
But according to your requirements, we must have $-100 \leq f(a) \leq 100$ and
$-100 \leq f(a + 5\times10^5) \leq 100.$ So
$$
\frac{-100 - 100}{5\times10^5} \leq \frac{f(a + 5\times10^5) - f(a)}{5\times10^5}
 \leq \frac{100 - (-100)}{5\times10^5},
$$
or more simply,
$$ -0.0004 \leq f'(a_1) \leq 0.0004 . $$

Now apply this fact to the two consecutive intervals
$(b, b + 5\times10^5)$ and $(b + 10^6, b + 1.5\times10^6)$ where
$10^6 \leq b \leq 8.5\times10^6.$
According to the previous result, there exist numbers $b_1 \in (b, b + 5\times10^5)$
and $b_2 \in (b + 10^6, b + 1.5\times10^6)$ such that
$ -0.0004 \leq f'(b_1) \leq 0.0004 $
and $ -0.0004 \leq f'(b_2) \leq 0.0004. $
The MVT now tells us that for some number $b_3 \in (b_1, b_2),$
$$
f''(b_3) = \frac{f(b_2) - f(b_1)}{b_2 - b_1}.
$$
But from $ -0.0004 \leq f'(b_1) \leq 0.0004 $
and $ -0.0004 \leq f'(b_2) \leq 0.0004 $ we get
$$
\frac{-0.0004 - 0.0004}{b_2 - b_1} \leq \frac{f(b_2) - f(b_1)}{b_2 - b_1}
 \leq \frac{0.0004 - (- 0.0004)}{b_2 - b_1},
$$
that is,
$$
\frac{-0.0008}{b_2 - b_1} \leq f''(b_3) \leq \frac{0.0008}{b_2 - b_1}.
$$
But since $b_1 < b + 5\times10^5$ and $b_2 > b + 10^6,$
we know that $b_2 - b_1 > 5\times10^5$ and therefore
$$
-1.6 \times 10^{-11} < f''(b_3) < 1.6 \times 10^{-11}
$$
for some number $b_3$ in the interval $(b, b + 1.5 \times 10^6),$
that is, in some subinterval of width $(1.5 \times 10^6)$
within the interval $(10^6, 10^7).$

Now for $10^6 \leq c \leq 6 \times 10^6,$
consider the intervals $(c, c + 1.5 \times 10^6)$ and
$(c + 2.5 \times 10^6, c + 4 \times 10^6),$
two subintervals of width $(1.5 \times 10^6)$ within the interval $(10^6, 10^7).$
From the previous result we know there is a number $c_1 \in (c, c + 1.5 \times 10^6)$
and a number $c_2 \in (c + 2.5 \times 10^6, c + 4 \times 10^6)$ such that
$ -1.6 \times 10^{-11} < f'(c_1) < 1.6 \times 10^{-11} $
and $ -1.6 \times 10^{-11} < f'(c_2) < 1.6 \times 10^{-11}. $
We apply the MVT again -- by now you should see the pattern and be able to fill in the steps -- to conclude that
$$
\frac{-3.2 \times 10^{-11}}{c_2 - c_1} < f'''(c_3)
 < \frac{3.2 \times 10^{-11}}{c_2 - c_1},
$$
and since $c_2 - c_1 > 10^6,$
$$
-3.2 \times 10^{-17} < f'''(c_3) < 3.2 \times 10^{-17}
$$
for some $c_3$ within an arbitrary subinterval of width $3 \times 10^6$
within the the interval $(10^6, 10^7).$

Now apply the same procedure once more to two subintervals of width $3 \times 10^6$
within the the interval $(10^6, 10^7),$
namely the intervals $(10^6, 4\times10^6)$ and $(7\times10^6, 10^7).$
This time the MVT gives us
$$
\frac{-6.4 \times 10^{-17}}{d_2 - d_1} < f'''(d_3)
 < \frac{6.4 \times 10^{-17}}{d_2 - d_1}
$$
for some $d_1 \in (10^6, 4\times10^6),$ $d_2 \in (7\times10^6, 10^7),$
and $d_3 \in (d_1, d_2).$
Then since $d_2 - d_1 > 3 \times 10^6$ and since $6.4 / 3 < 2.2,$
$$
-2.2 \times 10^{-23} < f^{(4)}(c_3) < 2.2 \times 10^{-23}.
$$
But since $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ or less, $f^{(4)}(x)$ is a constant.

This means that $f'''(x)$ can increase by at most
$(6 \times 10^6)(2.2 \times 10^{-23}) = 1.32 \times 10^{-16}$
within the interval $(0, 6\times10^6).$
But $f'''(x_1) > -3.2 \times 10^{-17}$ for some
$x_1 \in (3\times10^6, 6\times10^6),$ so $f'''(x)$ cannot be less than
$-3.2 \times 10^{-17} - 1.32 \times 10^{-16} = -1.64 \times 10^{-16}$ anywhere
in the interval $(0,x_1),$ and in particular in the subinterval $(0,3\times10^6).$

But now $f''(x)$ can decrease by at most
$(3 \times 10^6)(1.64 \times 10^{-16}) = 4.92 \times 10^{-10}$
within the interval $(0, 3\times10^6).$
Since $f''(x_2) < 1.6 \times 10^{-11}$ for some
$x_2 \in (1.5\times10^6, 3\times10^6),$ $f''(x)$ cannot exceed
$1.6 \times 10^{-11} + 4.92 \times 10^{-10} = 5.08 \times 10^{-10}$
in the interval $(0,x_1),$ and in particular in the subinterval $(0,1.5\times10^6).$

This means $f'(x)$ can increase by at most
$(1.5 \times 10^6)(5.08 \times 10^{-10}) = 0.000762$
within the interval $(0, 1.5\times10^6).$
Since $f'(x_3) \geq -0.0004$ for some $x_3 \in (10^6, 1.5\times10^6),$
$f'(x)$ cannot be less than $-0.0004 - 0.000762 = -0.001162$
in the interval $(0,x_3),$ and in particular in the subinterval $(0,10^6).$

This means that in the interval $(0,10^6),$
$f(x)$ cannot decrease by more than $10^6 \times -0.001162 = 1162.$
But since $f(10^6) = 100,$ it follows that $f(0) \leq 1262.$

In conclusion, there is no polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $4$ or less such that
$\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq 100$ for $10^6 < x < 10^7$ and $f(0) = 10^6.$

---

You might want to reconsider whether the interpolating function has to be a polynomial.

Comment: this is really impressive work, thank you funny enough I think I could use the f(x) = 1262 Polynomial, how do I go about getting the coefficients from these bound calculation?

Comment: And what If I squared the results I could get better results obviously but that's equivalent to increasing the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: In all those applications of the MVT, the bounds on the derivatives and value of the polynomial are valid but not very sharp. I don't an actual quartic can get close to those bounds. My best attempts have ended up quite "wavy", maybe a little less so than in the other answer but still nowhere near what you need. You could take a higher power of one of these wavy polynomials and scale it, or you could try something of the form $f(x)=100e^{-k(10^{-6}x-1)}+m(x-10^6)$; then $f(10^6)=100,$ you can set $k$ to make $f(0)$ as large as you want, and you can then set $m$ so that $f(10^7)=10.$

Comment: Ahh the exponential, the problem is I currently have 200 different functions as the x parameter, and so if I were to utilize the power series expansion of e^x, I would need higher order powers of x^n which will mean I will have a really large amount of functions to compute.

Comment: I was thinking exponential+linear since it's relatively easy to find the right coefficients to satisfy your requirements and I assumed you were going to have a computer do any further calculations (even squaring arbitrary numbers for your polynomials would get tiresome to do by hand), so you wouldn't have to worry about the Taylor expansion of the exponential. Also it's a nice convex function with no "waviness".

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is *no*, but I'm unsure how to prove it.

Let
$$
g(y) := f(y * 1e6) / 10
$$
Then your problem is equivalent to asking if there is a degree 4 polynomial $g$ where
$$
g(0) = 1e5,
g(1) = 10,
g(10) = 1
$$
and $\text{abs}(g(x)) \leq 10 $ for $x \in \left[1,10\right]$.

The interpolation problem has a unique solution in degree 2 and infinitely many solutions in degree 3 and 4.

However, even with 2 extra degrees of freedom, the scaling in the first term means that $g$ will be very "wavy" between 1 and 10. See for example this lagrange interpolation in sagemath:
[image: interpolation]

(you can fiddle with different constants in your own environment -- the graph ends up roughly the same.)

This is not even close to your desired bounds.

In terms of actually showing that *any* interpolation fails your bounds, I think you could prove it by looking at the local maximum/minimum in the longest interval between 1 and 10 where there are no roots. Since the degree is bounded, this interval has length at least 3. $g$ probably jumps to some value greater than 10 in that interval.

Comment: thanks this is really illuminating.